# Como juntar 2 consultas de SQL em uma única (uma é um calculo medio de valor e outra criterio de busca com BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select

Estou montando um sistema que encontra os prestadores em uma região específica, calcula o valor médio cobrado por eles e traz esse valor.

Mas antes disso ele só vai pegar os prestadores que estão disponiveis na data requisitada. Tenho essas 2 consultas feitas e separadas, mas não estou conseguindo uma forma de juntar ambas em uma única.

Consulta da regra de disponibilidade:

```
SELECT *
FROM fcs_prestadores_pedidos
WHERE hora_entrada not BETWEEN '2017-08-10 16:00:00' AND '2017-08-10 18:00:00'
AND hora_saida not between '2017-08-10 16:00:00' AND '2017-08-10 18:00:00'
```

Consulta com calculo do valor médio dentro do raio de 90km

```
SELECT avg(valor)
FROM (SELECT valor,(6371 * acos( cos( radians(-23.5427450) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-46.6513010) ) + sin( radians(-23.5427450) ) * sin( radians( lat ))))
AS distancia
FROM fcs_prestadores) virtual
WHERE distancia < 90
```

Como posso fazer ele primeiro fazer a consulta de disponibilidade, para em seguida calcular o valo médio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize a cláusula `NOT EXISTS` na segunda `query` utilizando os valores da primeira:

```
SELECT AVG(virtual.valor) AS valor,
       virtual.id
  FROM (SELECT fp.valor,
               (6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(-23.5427450)) * COS(RADIANS(fp.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(fp.lng) - RADIANS(-46.6513010)) + SIN(RADIANS(-23.5427450)) * SIN(RADIANS(fp.lat)))) AS distancia,
               fp.id
          FROM fcs_prestadores fp) virtual
 WHERE virtual.distancia < 90
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM fcs_prestadores_pedidos fpp
                   WHERE fpp.prestador_id = virtual.id
                     AND (fpp.hora_entrada BETWEEN '2017-08-10 16:00:00' AND '2017-08-10 18:00:00'
                      OR fpp.hora_saida BETWEEN '2017-08-10 16:00:00' AND '2017-08-10 18:00:00'))
 GROUP BY virtual.id
```

As alterações realizadas na `query` foram:

- Adicionado o `id` no retorno da tabela `fcs_prestadores` para que seja comparado com a `fcs_prestadores_pedidos`;
- `GROUP BY` por `id` do prestador para garantir que será mostrada uma linha para cada um;
- `NOT EXISTS` verificará se existe pedido para o prestador determinado no intervalo desejado. O vínculo é feito pela coluna `id`.

---

> [`GROUP BY Modifiers`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)
>
> The `GROUP BY` clause permits a `WITH ROLLUP` modifier that causes summary output to include extra rows that represent higher-level (that is, super-aggregate) summary operations. `ROLLUP` thus enables you to answer questions at multiple levels of analysis with a single query. For example, `ROLLUP` can be used to provide support for `OLAP (Online Analytical Processing)` operations.
>
> Suppose that a sales table has year, country, product, and profit columns for recording sales profitability:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales(
>   year    INT,
>   country VARCHAR(20),
>   product VARCHAR(32),
>   profit  INT
> );
> ```
>
> To summarize table contents per year, use a simple `GROUP BY` like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT year, SUM(profit) AS profit
>   FROM sales
>  GROUP BY year;
>
> +------+--------+
> | year | profit |
> +------+--------+
> | 2000 |   4525 |
> | 2001 |   3010 |
> +------+--------+
> ```

Em tradução livre:

> A cláusula `GROUP BY` permite um modificador`WITH ROLLUP` que faz com que a saída de resumo inclua linhas extras que representam operações de resumo de nível superior (isto é, super agregadas). O `ROLLUP` permite-lhe responder a questões em múltiplos níveis de análise com uma única consulta. Por exemplo, `ROLLUP` pode ser usado para fornecer suporte para operações`OLAP (Online Analytical Processing)`.
>
> Suponha que uma tabela de vendas tenha colunas de ano, país, produto e lucro para registrar a lucratividade das vendas:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales(
>   year    INT,
>   country VARCHAR(20),
>   product VARCHAR(32),
>   profit  INT
> );
> ```
>
> Para resumir o conteúdo da tabela por ano, use um `GROUP BY` simples assim:
>
> ```
> SELECT year, SUM(profit) AS profit
>   FROM sales
>  GROUP BY year;
>
> +------+--------+
> | year | profit |
> +------+--------+
> | 2000 |   4525 |
> | 2001 |   3010 |
> +------+--------+
> ```

Comment: Funcionou certinho. Só mais uma coisa, no avg(valor) sabe como posso adicionar tbm quem está dentro do criterio do raio, trazendo a coluna id? ex: avg(valor)110 - id 1 | avg(valor)110 id 2

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo alterei a `query` para que retorne por prestador

Comment: eu inverti o between para AND ('2017-08-10 16:00:00' BETWEEN fpp.hora_entrada AND fpp.hora_saida

ele está trazendo o valor de cada e o id deles, queria que trouxesse o valor medio em algum lugar.